# Xamarin iOS project suddenly gives 200+ errors (Visual Studio for Windows)

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

After four weeks, I returned to my Xamarin project in Visual Studio to finish my app, I updated Visual Studio on my Windows PC, I updated XCode on my Mac and when I try to launch emulator, I get this:

[image]

I changed nothing in the code, it worked previously. The only thing I can think of that could f*ck all up is I was trying to prepare my app for testing (so I was doing some stuff in developer account settings, provisioning etc.)

Does anyone know how to fix this, or at least what it means?
Thanks!

Comment: did you update VS on the Mac to match?  Have you tried building directly on the Mac?  Have you cleaned your solution and deleted all bin/obj folders?

Comment: @Jason thank you so much for your response, i got it working now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out the problem was in version mismatch :) All I needed to do was click "Update on Mac" in the "Connect to Mac" window.